# What is meant by [protein name]+/- (ie "Myod+" and "Myod-")

Tags: proteins, nomenclature

I have read a paper where this notation for protein names is used:

> *Myod*+ and *Myod*-

(or another example, *Myog*+, *Myog*-).

**What does this indicate**?  In the paper I'm reading, and some brief googling, it seems that *Myog* is itself a protein, and not that there are two kinds called *Myog*+ and *Myog*-.

Examples are [here (the one I'm reading)](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-019-0969-x#Sec1) (Figure 6c), or [here](https://www.cell.com/stem-cell-reports/pdf/S2213-6711(18)30053-5.pdf) (page 3, pdf page (journal page 958)).

Comment: The paper you linked is not open-access, so many people won't be able to help you. However, as a common convention, *ProtX+* and *ProtX-* typically refer to cells, tissues, or individuals that either express or don't express a particular Protein X.

Comment: Oh okay, that makes sense.  Thank you.  Sorry I didn't realize it wasn't open source.  It looks like the second one is available though (if I open in incognito, I can access)

Comment: To expand on @MattDMo , italicized names indicate genes, with the + or – being used to describe either genome or cell with or without an active copy of the gene and thus able to make the protein, the name of which may or may not be the unitalicized form of the gene. (Many genes are named for the phenotype they convey or some other reason when they are discovered before the protein product has been identified.)

Comment: @David or.......

Comment: @MattDMo either of those could make a concise answer. Probably not a lot of reference needed for an answer like this; one example might be nice but not really necessary.

Comment: @MattDMo — Do you want to follow up Bryan’s suggestion?

Comment: @David I did...

Comment: @MattDMo — Good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *Stem Cell Reports* paper linked in the question is open-access, so anyone can download it freely. Unfortunately the *Nature* paper is not.

There are two different abbreviation conventions being used in the open paper – *MyoD+*/*MyoD-* and MyoD+/MyoD-. The italicized version indicates the genotype of the cell, tissue, or individual being referenced, so for example *MyoD-* indicates the *MyoD* knockout they made. This convention is very widely used to refer to genes or mRNA.

Examples where the gene name is not italicized refer to the protein product of that particular gene and its presence or absence. So, MyoD+ cells express the wild-type protein, while MyoD- cells do not. This convention is also very widely used to refer to the presence or absence of the indicated protein.

Comment: Are there rules on the site against me sharing the part of the figure I am talking about (that is not open access)?

Comment: @user8243 it may be copyright infringement, but I'm not a lawyer.

Comment: I think my smaller question doesn't require it.  Reading through the methods, it seems all of their cells are from embryo sample, and no genes were explicitly knocked out.  Then here, does the minus indicate that no expression was observed?  Seems like it follows from your answer, but wanted to check

Comment: @user8243 the minus can either be used to describe a KO ("no expression is *expected*"), or to describe the results of an assay where expression is actually *tested*, such as immunofluorescence or Western blotting.